# async-await in asp.net core web api (not MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have this http post controller method to insert a new text message to db. Here I want to change this method to async method. I tried but still couldn't do it. Can anyone help me? :)

**This is my controller method**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult<Message> Create(Message message)
    {
        var duplicatemessage = _messageService.DuplicateMessage(message.Text);
        if (duplicatemessage == null)
        {
            _messageService.Create(message);
            return CreatedAtRoute("Api", new { id = message.Id.ToString() }, message);
        }
        else
        {
            return BadRequest(new { message = "Text Already Exist" });
        }
    }
```

**These are my service class methods related to the controller post method**

```
public Message DuplicateMessage(string Text)
    {
        return _messages.Find<Message>(message => message.Text == Text).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public Message Create(Message message)
    {
        _messages.InsertOne(message);
        return message;
    }
```

Comment: i see no db code

Comment: hi @Steve I actually didn't put db code here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult<Message>> Create(Message message)
    {
        var duplicatemessage =  await _messageService.DuplicateMessage(message.Text);
        if (duplicatemessage == null)
        {
            _messageService.Create(message);
            return CreatedAtRoute("Api", new { id = message.Id.ToString() }, message);
        }
        else
        {
            return BadRequest(new { message = "Text Already Exist" });
        }
    }


public async Task<Message> DuplicateMessage(string Text)
    {
        return await _messages.Set<Message>().Where(message => message.Text == 
 Text).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Sergey thank u so much this worked for me. I had to change a little bit in service class which is,

`public async Task<Message> DuplicateMessage(string Text)
        {
            return await _messages.Find<Message>(message => message.Text == Text).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        }`

But thank u for helping :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to implement the async method into your controller (i assume this is what you want).  You must first make the function, DuplicateMessage or  async.  You can do that by making the return type a task and running it in a task.